# Google Pay Integration in Flutter web crashing

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, payment-gateway

I have installed the package pay 1.1.2 for my project with Flutter version 3.16.8, Dart 3.2.5 and DevTools 2.28.5. I am trying to integrate Google Pay payment gateway but my code crashes.

My pubspec.yaml is defined as follows:

[pubspec.yaml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/137RQAk4RGw3Xsgw15fk1GKn4J_HwMro2/view?usp=sharing)

The code for file where I am getting the issue is as follows:

[PaymentCheckout.dart](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WEIxUGtUuRwtnGW72SqWB0_cIRNUVtbL/view?usp=sharing)

I have defined the constant defaultGooglePayConfig as follows:

[gpay.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v0lEkFuw2Kh4zN0wI8O6L1UUk1R72rmW/view?usp=sharing)

The error I am getting is as follows:

[image: Unsupported Operation error]

I have separated the payment gateway configuration settings and tried to use paymentConfigurationAsset as follows:

```
GooglePayButton(
                                  paymentConfigurationAsset: 'gpay.json',
                                  paymentItems: [PaymentItem(amount: amount)],
                                  type: GooglePayButtonType.pay,
                                  onPaymentResult: (Map resultJson) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      result = '$resultJson';
                                    });
                                  },
                                )
```

Here I am not getting any error but button is also not visible. Empty space is there as follows:

[image: Empty space below screenshot]